# In what situations template parameters missing is allowed in C++ function?

Tags: c++, templates, static, struct

It is a C++ code, why line 3 has an error:

template struct sum used without template parameters

```
template<class T> void foo(T op1, T op2)
{
  cout<< "op1 = " << op1 << endl;
  cout<< "op2 = " << op2 << endl;

 }

 template<class T>
 struct sum
 {
    static void foo(T op1 , T op2)
    {
      cout << "sum is " << op1 << endl;
    }
 };


 int main()
 {
   foo(1,3);   // line 1
   foo<int>(1, '3'); // line 2
   sum::foo(1,2); // line 3
   return 0;
 }
```

Line 1 has no template parameters, but it has no error.

Thanks !

Comment: 1)  Template argument deduction 2) Explict template arguments 3) No template arguments -- Error

Comment: Search for "template argument deduction" and read 14.8.2 from standard - all the information you need is there.

Answer (score 5):

Line 3 is trying to use a member of a class template.

The compiler can/will (at least attempt to) deduce types for function template parameters. In a few cases, it can't deduce the type, so you need to specify it explicitly.

The compiler will *not* attempt to deduce the type for a class template parameter.

Therefore, line 3 needs to be something like `sum<int>::foo(1, 2);`. By itself, `sum` is only the name of a class template, not of a class. The name preceding the `::` needs to be the name of a class (or a namespace).

Comment: Well, *never* as in *not yet*.  Constructor syntax allowing template argument deduction has been proposed for future iterations of C++.  Basically, eliminating the need to write quite so many `foo<blah> make_foo( blah b )` functions.

Comment: @user2420472: The short answer is that it's just how the standard was written.